# Determine the container class of an object in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-composition

`Class1` is instantiated in `Class2` as follows. `Class2` also contains another variable, say:

```
class Class2: 
    class1 = Class1()
    a = 0
```

I want to create a method `myDef()` in `Class1` that can read or write to `a`. How do I access `a` from within `myDef()` to access `a`?

Comment: ... By accessing it through `Class2`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Can you give a code example?

Comment: `print(Class2.a)`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Thanks but Class1 does not have any knowledge about its container class a priori. Also, this will hardcode the path. I want to know of a built-in method (kind of equivalent of super() for inheritance) that will give me the container class reference, Class2 in this case.